# How do I find Ancient Ruin Sites in Elite: Dangerous?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I took on the Community Goal in January 2017, in which a NPC named Ram Tah calls for players to gather data from Ancient Ruins. The Community Goal indicates the star system that the data is located in, but what do I do once I actually get to the system?

I also got a separate mission from Ram Tah, when I docked at **Felice Dock** in the **Meene** star system, which seems to correlate to the Community Goal, but shows up as a private mission.

**Question**: How do I find "Ancient Sites?"

Answer (score 3):

The ruins are mentioned a lot in the in-game lore in news bulletins.  You will need to go to the system, head towards the surface of the planet (you need the Horizons expansion to do this) and either hover very close or use an SRV to scan them.  But you can find them here (taken from the Wiki):

> System: Synuefe XR-H D11-102
>
> Planet: 1B
>
> Surface Co-ordinates:  -31.806, -128.937

Source: http://elite-dangerous.wikia.com/wiki/Ancient_Ruins

Comment: There are no artifacts to use on the ground :-(

Comment: The ruins at this particular site actually have a tourist beacon! It makes them _much_ easier to get to.